# How can i turn this sql statement into an abap statement?

Tags: abap, opensql

```
Select knvp.KUNNR, kna1.NAME1, knvp.PARVW, knvp.KUNN2
from landing.kna1 kna1,
landing.knvp knvp,
(Select kna1.KUNNR, COUNT(knvp.KUNN2) as count
from landing.KNA1 kna1
, landing.KNVP knvp
where kna1.KUNNR = knvp.KUNN2
and kna1.KTOKD in('ZPYR', 'ZBPR')
group by kna1.kunnr
having count(knvp.kunn2) < 2)as orphans
where kna1.KUNNR = knvp.KUNNR
and knvp.KUNNR = orphans.KUNNR
```

Basically this series of sql statements puts a counter on the kunnr table type and display all the numbers that only show up once in that table.

---

A pretty-printed version of the SQL-statement (This version is attached - just in case some important details get lost from the pretty printer):

```
SELECT knvp.kunnr, 
       kna1.name1, 
       knvp.parvw, 
       knvp.kunn2 
FROM   landing.kna1 kna1, 
       landing.knvp knvp, 
       (SELECT kna1.kunnr, 
               Count(knvp.kunn2) AS count 
        FROM   landing.kna1 kna1, 
               landing.knvp knvp 
        WHERE  kna1.kunnr = knvp.kunn2 
               AND kna1.ktokd IN ( 'ZPYR', 'ZBPR' ) 
        GROUP  BY kna1.kunnr 
        HAVING Count(knvp.kunn2) < 2) AS orphans 
WHERE  kna1.kunnr = knvp.kunnr 
       AND knvp.kunnr = orphans.kunnr 




im starting with this

rowNum     col1    col2    col3     col4
1          1234     bp     name1    1234
2          1234     py     name1    1234
3          1223     bp     name2    1223
4          1245     py     name3    1245
5          5432     py     name4    4432

i want to delete row# 1 and 2 because they have the same col1# but
different col2#

result:

rowNum     col1    col2    col3     col4
1          1223     bp     name2    1223
2          1245     py     name3    1245
3          5432     py     name4    5432
```

Comment: I can imagine, that is is possible, but often it is easier to solve it with a sequence of select-commands and some additional variable to store the intermediate results.

Comment: Ok could you give me an example i am new to abap programming i have only been programming for about a month.

Comment: Why did you tag this with both mysql and sql-server when you only want an ABAP response?

Comment: i really dont know what the sql statement does. i was going to ask somebody to explain what its doing but, haven't asked yet.

Comment: What are you trying to do - get the KUNNR keys (and some additional data) for all entries that have less than two entries with KUNN2 in KNVP?

Comment: I can tell you what it does - confuse everyone who is trying to decipher it. :-)

Comment: I still try to understand the SQL. Is the `landing.` needed? or just to confuse the reader? You use the two tables `KNA1` and `KNVP` in the select - but I don't see a `JOIN`.

Comment: yes thats what im tring to do but in abap.

Comment: knut, this isn't Open SQL. I'd say someone tore some tables out of a R/3 installation and stuffed them into a MySQL database named "landing" or something like that.

Comment: @knut i dont know much about the sql statements. it was given to me to make a abap report of the same data that the sql statement produces but with abap. if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT knvp~kunnr
       kna1~name1
       knvp~parvw
       knvp~kunn2
FROM kna1 JOIN knvp ON kna1~kunnr = knvp~kunnr
INTO TABLE lt_some_table_with_matching_structure
WHERE knvp~kunnr IN ( SELECT kna1~kunnr
                      FROM kna1 JOIN knvp ON kna1~kunnr = knvp~kunn2
                      WHERE ( kna1~ktokd = 'ZPYR' OR kna1~ktokd = 'ZBPR' )
                      GROUP BY kna1~kunnr
                      HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT knvp~kunn2 ) < 2 ).
```

but be aware that this is largely guesswork since I don't understand what the query is supposed to do at all.

EDIT: With the additional info from your comment, you might want to try something like this:

```
DATA: lt_partners TYPE TABLE OF kunnr. " unsure whether this is the correct type

SELECT kunnr 
  FROM kna1
  INTO TABLE lt_partners
  WHERE ( kna1~ktokd = 'ZPYR' OR kna1~ktokd = 'ZBPR' ).
  " AND probably some other filter criteria
SORT lt_partners.
DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM lt_partners. " avoid DISTINCT if you can to take load off the database

IF lt_partners IS NOT INITIAL.
  SELECT knvp~kunnr
         kna1~name1
         knvp~parvw
  FROM kna1 JOIN knvp ON kna1~kunnr = knvp~kunnr
  INTO TABLE lt_some_table_with_matching_structure
  FOR ALL ENTRIES IN lt_partners
  WHERE knvp~kunn2 = lt_partners-table_line
  GROUP BY knvp~kunnr kna1~name1 knvp~parvw
  HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT knvp~kunn2 ) < 2.
ENDIF.
```

Be aware that you can't select KNVP~KUNN2 in this step because you'd have to include it in the GROUP BY clause, and then the HAVING clause wouldn't work.
(I don't have a system available right now, so again, this is guesswork...)

Comment: It helped but its giving me the same results for the code that i have.

Comment: ...so? I assumed that you wanted it to return the same results? Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: It helped but its giving me the same results for the code that i have.  Its pulling and comparing the right data but not giving me the result im looking for.  i want to use some kind of counter to count the kunnr# that has one partner. For the ones that have one partner# connected to it print that kunnr#. the info im getting now is all kunnr# with two partner# connected to them im trying to figure a way to just pick out the kunnr# with on partner connected to it. does that make more sense.

Comment: im working on it tryin to get it to work i will let you know how it goes.

Comment: hello vwegert i tried that solution and a modified part of the solution but its still not giving me the answer im looking for i think im going to illustrate what im starting with and what i want to finish with.